# MongoDB Operator for filtering documents which a specific field has only specified value?

Tags: mongodb

I want to fetch URLs  from the following collection  which status field has only 400 (result must be:  `b` and `c`). Does someone know any single  mongoDB query operator for this?

Collection:

```
url, status

  a,  200
  a,  400
  b,  400
  c,  400
```

Collection Image:

[image: 1]

Result must be:

```
b, c
```

How I want above mentioned result?

- Include only 400 status documents
- If URL and status are same then include only single document out of them
- If URL is same and status is different then don't include any out of them

Comment: @turivishal, I approved your edit. Now the question  is more clear. Great work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope i understand properly,

- `$group` by `url` and store all in `root` field

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$url",
      status: {
        $push: "$status"
      },
      root: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
```

- `$match` all elements that are not equal to `400` using `$ne` and `$not` for opposite match by `$ne`, it means equal to `400`

```
  /** MATCH ALL HAVE 400 STATUS*/
  {
    $match: {
      "status": {
        $not: {
          $elemMatch: {
            $ne: "400"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

- `$unwind` `root` variable and replace into root using `$replaceRoot`

```
  {
    $unwind: "$root"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$root"
    }
  },
```

- `$group` by `url` for removing duplicates if same status, create new variable `roots` and store "$$ROOT"

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$url",
      roots: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
```

- again `$replaceRoot` with `roots` variable

```
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$roots"
    }
  }
])
```

**Result:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "status": "400",
    "url": "c"
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "status": "400",
    "url": "b"
  }
]
```

Working Playground:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/C6tC8ho1t6M

Comment: And Can you check following playground : https://mongoplayground.net/p/VJJpSLT5Fi5 and guide me how to modify your query to get above expected result. just changed some of your data in the playground.

Comment: No result must have only single  c  url. i mean result must be same.

Comment: You can check answer updated and also playground link.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you take a look at [Official Documentation for 'find()'](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)

I don't know if you use javascript or something else, but your method for filtering after the `status` column would look like ('test' being your collection name):

```
db.test.find( { "status": "400" } )
```

This means that your will 'find' all the values for which your `status` column is **equal** to 400 as a **string**

Comment: I updated the question and  find is not the operator  to get the required result. Thanks for trying to answer the question!

Comment: What about something like [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)?

`db.test.distinct( 'status', { 'status': { '$ne': '200' }})`
This means that we get all the variables that are in `status` column, without those that are `200`

Comment: It would work only for this case. can think  of a more  general query using only 400 status in the query?